# Xcode not showing any connected devices

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, build

In Xcode 9.2 and iOS 11.2 wireless build not working. Xcode not showing any connected devices.

But upto iOS 11.1 it's working...

Comment: your connected device have iOS 11.0 or later ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reconnected my devices and restarted my Xcode once again. Now it's working fine ....

Answer (score 1):

You need to add DeveloperDiskImage.dmg for iOS 11.2 in following path.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.2

And restart your Xcode. First connect your device with cable, it will reinstall your device for iOS 11.2 in Xcode.

Comment: You can download developer disk from here: https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/tree/master/11.2%20(15C5097c) Download both file and put in above path.

Comment: I reconnected my devices and restarted my Xcode once again. Now it's working fine thank u ....

Comment: Welcome always.